# Indefinite integration of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

> Find the integration of $\sec^2 x \cos (\tan x)$.

I am not sure about how to solve the $\cos (\tan x)$ part...

Please help I have tried rewriting $\sec^2 x$ as $1+\tan^2 x$ but not able to proceed further.

Comment: Set  $$\tan x=y\implies dy=?$$

Comment: When you look at the integrand, it should shout "Chain Rule!"

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\tan x$ to be $y$.

Therefore $\tan x=y,\,$
and $\sec^2(x) dx = dy$

Substituting in the problem we get

$\int  (y) dy =sin (y) +c $

As $y = \tan x,\;\sin (\tan x) +c,\;$ is the final answer.

Comment: Please add this as an edit to your posted question. You can edit your own questions.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.